# How to use client_side_validations and Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I found [this blog post](http://www.ddarrensmith.com/blog/2012/05/17/ruby-on-rails-client-side-validation-with-validation-helpers-and-twitter-bootstrap/) that talks about how to incorporate `client_side_validations` along with Twitter Bootstrap. But in the blog post, the author is using SimpleForm.

**Anyone know how I can achieve the same results but without using `SimpleForm`?**

On my application, I'm using `form_for` and don't want to convert the entire project over to `SimpleForm` since it'll take a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Check this video http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations?view=asciicast

I'm using client_side_validations with form_for

The gem simple_form is instaled on my enviroment

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should have mentioned that I followed this very RailsCast to set up the client_side_validations. But the tutorial goes over how to do it with SimpleForm and doesn't cover integrating Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: I'm using BootStrap too.    The onlye difference that I got, is that the error message appear under the input item, not  beside it, like in the video.

Comment: Ya, same here. But I don't want the standard error message. I want the error message to appear on the right and then have the text field highlighted red like they have on the [Twitter Bootstrap form validation section](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms).

Answer (score 0):

I've spent hours mucking about with this trying to get it to work without using SimpleForm...in the end I gave up. Use SimpleForm, the nice client_side_validations plugin, and save your sanity - took me about 10 minutes to get it working.

In your Gemfile:

```
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'client_side_validations'
gem 'client_side_validations-simple_form'
```

then run this:

```
rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap
```

then your form will need to look something like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@qualification, :validate => true, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :year %>
<% end %>
```

...and that's it.